# Sims 2 gives blue screen of death while playing on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, the-sims-2, technical-issues

I've installed sims 2 on windows 7 and am playing with my cd present in the drive. Everything goes fine for a few minutes and I can start playing the tutorial. However, in the middle of the tutorial I get the blue screen of death and I need to restart my computer with the message that my graphics drivers stopped responding.

I'm having a built-in graphics card which shows up as "Mobile Intel(R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)". This is the latest driver for my card and I'm sure there are no malwares/viruses etc (I've also done a complete scan with ESET security 4 and cleaned the registry with ccleaner).

In `dxdiag` I see DirectX 11 so I don't think this version should be a problem.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can deal with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To whomsoever it may concern I was able to solve this problem. The very first problem was being able to run SIMS 2. I solved this by going to compatibility tab and checking "run as administrator" tab.

After running the crashes were probably due to SIMS 2 problems with windows 7. I found a patch online in the ea sims website (under cd/dvd section) which addressed this issue.

Thanks for looking into this anyways and let me know if anyone wants more info.